# Sphinx searcing related has_many and has_one with thinkingsphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

### Hello!,I am confused with the thinking_sphinx index

I have some models,there are **Bill** ,**LineItem** and **product**

```
Bill has_many :line_items
LineItem has_one  :product
```

the Product have two attributes: number and name

#### example:

```
bill.line_items.first.product.number = "product"
```

I want to find the this bill with the key word "product"

how to define the index?

Thanks!

ps:Hope you can understand me,my English is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this in Bill model:

```
define_index do
  indexes line_items.product(:name)
  indexes line_items.product(:number)
end
```

Now you can search like this:

```
Bill.search('some product name')
```